# Any background process gems that work with JRuby deployed on Windows?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jruby

Does anyone know a working background job solution for JRuby deployed on a windows server? (via warbler and tomcat)

I'm looking for a way to schedule background jobs from my Rails 3.2 app, so that the web app can respond immediately rather than hang up while a long running job runs.

I tried the delayed_job gem, except it doesn't seem to work with JRuby and Windows. (If I'm wrong, please enlighten me) Resque depends on redis which evidently doesn't support Windows. I don't have experience with Beanstalkd or Starling, but the documentation for them doesn't mention windows.

I'ld love to dump windows, believe me, but the background job is a windows executable that did not come with source. And I need to use JRuby to be able to call some Java code too.

Comment: I haven't tested `delayed_job` on Rails 3.x, but I have used it with Rails 2.x and JRuby for a long time. What is the error you are encountering?

Comment: On a windows server? The problem is in getting the worker job to start. I'll post the exact error as soon as I get back to the network with the problem.

Comment: The command "jruby -X+O delayed_job start" gets "NotImplementedError: fork is not available on this platform"

Comment: Unfortunately, its on a network that is not connected to the Internet, so I can't easily post the stack trace without typing it in by hand. But the message proves the point. JRuby does not implement the fork method on Windows, and delayed_job uses daemons which requires fork evidently. Solved the problem using the jruby-rack-worker gem, https://github.com/kares/jruby-rack-worker, which let's you used delayed_job to schedule jobs, just provides a different way to kickoff worker processes.

Comment: I have encountered such issues before with Sunspot, it is the matter of creating a different rake task for starting the worker. Should be straightforward. With the stack-trace it is easy to locate the errant code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved the problem using the jruby-rack-worker gem, http://github.com/kares/jruby-rack-worker, which let's you use delayed_job to schedule jobs, just provides a different way to kickoff worker processes that is more JRuby/Warbler/Tomcat friendly.

Comment: If you're going to downgrade my answer, which just posted the solution I found with a link, at least be courteous enough to explain your reason.

Comment: @JeffK This answer is over 4 years old at this point. I know I tested it with Tomcat, and I seem to remember we got it to work with JBOSS as well. Never tried it with Weblogic or Websphere. Given 4 years of new developments and new versions of Rails and JRuby, there probably are other options available now.

Answer (score 3):

We use [Rufus Scheduler](https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler) for that purpose. The scheduler configuration sits in an initializer file like so:

```
scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.start_new  
scheduler.every('1d') do
  puts "I run once every day"
end

scheduler.every '3h' do
  puts "I run every 3 hours"
end
```

Comment: I've had issues with Rufus working on various application containers in the past. What application container are you using and what jRuby version?

Comment: We were using PIK and the latest JRuby version available at that time. However, please note that this answer is 4 years old by now, so things might have changed considerably. If in doubt, please go ahead and create a new question on SO.

Comment: Can you please give an idea how you were able to start a worker with Rufus scheduler? We use Rufus to schedule some jobs and now are looking into using Delayed Jobs for some async processing. It would be really helpful if we can start a worker using Rufus scheduler.